# symfony2 get property values from form

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a symfony entity called Config

```
class Config
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="key_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $keyName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="key_value", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $keyValue;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="key_type", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $keyType;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="key_tab", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $keyTab;
```

controller :

```
class ConfigController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Config entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Config')->findAll();

    $configCollection = array('configs'=>$entities);

    $collection = $this->createForm(new ConfigsType, $configCollection);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Config:index.html.twig', array(
        'edit_form' => $collection->createView(),

    ));
}
```

view :

```
{% macro config_row(elem) %}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form_label(elem.keyValue, 'fff', { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'col-md-3 control-label' }}) }}
{# elem.keyName|humanize #}
<div class="col-md-4">
     {{ form_widget(elem.keyValue, {'attr': { 'class': 'form-control input-large' }}) }}
     {{ form_errors(elem.keyValue) }}

</div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}

<form action="{{ path('my_config') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }} >
 {% for conf in edit_form.configs %} 
      {{ _self.config_row(conf) }} 
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
 {{ form_rest(edit_form) }}
 </form>
```

what i need is for each config row i can get properties values in the config_row template to customize html rows structure based on their values

any idea please ?

thank you.

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you please reword it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to retrieve the value of each property of instance of entity Config, right?

If so, properties should be accessible by doing this:

```
{{ conf.vars.data.id }}
{{ conf.vars.data.keyName }}
{{ conf.vars.data.keyValue }}
```